# Ubuntu 13.10 x64 skype

Tags: skype

Fresh install ubuntu 13.10 x64: no skype in software center, no mouse speed adjustment... I have tried numerous Terminal tricks, following amatory blogs. P

Comment: If you want knowledgeable answers you need to provide knowledge yourself so I removed that part. I would expect from your part to include anything you tried yourself before asking something like that ;)

Answer (score 1):

Download the .deb from [here](http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-computer/) (choose ubuntu 12.04)
Then install it : `sudo dpkg -i "path to deb file"`

Comment: Have you tested it your self?

Comment: this is how i installed it

Comment: This will potentially leave your dependencies broken... dpkg don't fulfill dependencies...

Comment: i don't know about you guys, but i installed it from the official site long before i knew it was in the repos (had no problems).